# Redis instance swap usage continues to grow

Tags: spring, redis, amazon-elasticache, spring-session

I have an AWS Elasticache Redis instance that I'm using as a backing for Spring Session.

Looking at the console most of the metrics seem to be ok, but I'm concerned that the swap usage is growing like there's some sort of memory leak.

I'm new to Redis and Spring Session. Is this something I should be concerned about? How can I resolve this?

For reference, here's a screenshot:
[image: stack continuing to grow]

Comment: Is this the swap for the Redis instance or your Java app?

Comment: This swap graph is specifically for the Redis instance.

Comment: Anything else using the Redis? Are the number of keys growing? Spring Session keys should have ttl on them. Any bots hitting your service that create sessions (search engine crawler, health checks, etc)?

Comment: I do have monitoring and a load balancer health check, so those would probably create a session. Any way to disable session creation for specific endpoints? The number of keys isn't growing. All the other graphs seem normal.

Comment: To prevent a session from being created ensure that you don't invoke HttpServletRequest.getSession() or HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)

Comment: Is there a way I can empirically discover if I am actually creating a session or not for an endpoint?

Comment: Yes. If the response contains a session id (i.e. SESSION cookie)